# How to fix My Account menu link in Magento 2.1 after migration from 1.9

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, customer-account, migration

We have upgraded our store from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1. the My Account is link to `/index.php/account` it should link to `/index.php/customer/account/`

We are using `Solwin FreeGo theme` for Magento 2. Please do let me know how to fix this issues so that My Account will link through `/index.php/customer/account/`

Answer (score 0):

You can change my account link from ***Url.php*** file which is located at

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Model folder.
```

Find ***getAccountUrl() function*** and change url in it. But change in directly core file is not a good idea so i suggest you override model file and then do changes as per your need.

> For Override Model in Magento 2 refer below link:
>
> https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/